# How to set the overwrite option in Mahout?

Tags: java, apache, maven, mahout, overwrite

In many cases the output directory needs to be overwritten, say while [Converting Sequence files into Sparse Vectors](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.9/org/apache/mahout/vectorizer/SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.java).
I would like to know how to set the [overwrite](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.9/org/apache/mahout/vectorizer/SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.java#138) option.

P.S.: I have been able to do the same via the CLI but I need to make use APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API call used in [Sparse vectors from Sequence files](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.9/org/apache/mahout/vectorizer/SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles.java) is as follows:

```
String[] vectorizingParameters = {"-i", seqDirectory,
                                  "-o", vectorsDirectory,
                                  "-ow"};
SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles thisSparseVectorizer = new SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles();
thisSparseVectorizer.run(vectorizingParameters);
```

It's that **-ow** in the end of the `String[] vectorizingParameters` which gets parsed as overwrite option.